# escaping special character while executing commands remotely using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, escaping

When ran commands locally on the remote server outputs would work as expected:

```sh
desired_kernel_version="5.4.0-105-generic"

cat /tmp/grb.bkp | grep GRUB_DEFAULT
GRUB_DEFAULT=0

kernel_position=$(awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " || $1=="submenu " {print i++ " : " $2}; /\tmenuentry / {print "\t" i-1">"j++ " : " $2};' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "${desired_kernel_version}" | grep -v recovery | awk '{ print $1}' | sed 's/ //g')

echo $k_position
1>2

sed -i "s/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT=\"${k_position}\"/g" /tmp/grb.bkp

cat /tmp/grb.bkp | grep GRUB_DEFAULT
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

desired output when ran from remote server:
replace 0 of GRUB_DEFAULT value to kernel_position within quotes.

```sh
server=abcd

kernel_position=$(ssh -qT $server awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " || $1=="submenu " {print i++ " : " $2}; /\tmenuentry / {print "\t" i-1">"j++ " : " $2};' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "${desired_kernel_version}" | grep -v recovery | awk '{ print $1}' | sed 's/ //g')

ssh -qT $server "sed -i "s/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT=\"${k_position}\"/g" /tmp/grb.bkp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to avoid quoting hell.

Send muli-line command into `ssh` by writing a script `remote-script.sh` with all lines.

#### remote-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
$k_position=$1
desired_kernel_version="5.4.0-105-generic"

cat /tmp/grb.bkp | grep GRUB_DEFAULT
GRUB_DEFAULT=0

kernel_position=$(awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " || $1=="submenu " {print i++ " : " $2}; /\tmenuentry / {print "\t" i-1">"j++ " : " $2};' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "${desired_kernel_version}" | grep -v recovery | awk '{ print $1}' | sed 's/ //g')

echo $k_position
1>2

sed -i "s/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT=\"${k_position}\"/g" /tmp/grb.bkp

cat /tmp/grb.bkp | grep GRUB_DEFAULT
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

Give current user execution permissions on `remote-script.sh`

```
chmod u+x remote-script.sh
```

Use `scp` command to copy `remote-script.sh` to `$server`. If possible only once at deploy time.

```
scp -q remote-script.sh $server:/home/your-user
```

Use `ssh` command to run `remote-script.sh` on remote server. Pass `$k_position` in command line.

```
ssh -qT $server "bash -c /home/your-user/remote-script.sh $k_position"
```

BTW, in computing `kernel_position`, suggesting to fold all `awk`, `grep`, `sed` commands into a single `awk` script.